# How to store IP in the PHPSESSID?

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

Today I learned the difference between COOKIES and SESSION.

Now I would like to create a login. The main idea is the following:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$session_ip = $_SESSION['PHPSESSID']['ip'];

if ( (session_id() === $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) && ($ip === $session_id) ){
    return (true);
} else {
    return (false);
}
```

I would like to check if the IP is the same like that one that an User had last time when he logged in.
So when the SESION starts it will create the `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` on client site. The server will store the SESSION some where on the server and can identify the SESSION with `session_id()`

Basically it should be the same like this part says:

```
session_id() === $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']
```

Now, the probem is the part saving the IP to that SESSION.

How can I access this SESSION to handle it like an Array? Normally I would do it like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']['ip'] = $ip;
```

So I just save the IP to the client site `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` but what about the SESSION from the server site? How can I store the IP there?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Do you mean `$ip === $session_ip` instead of `$ip === $session_id`?

Comment: Keep in mind that some people have IP addresses that change with every request, such as if they're in a large network like a business or university. IP locks can be a bad idea.

Comment: its just to ensure no abuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saving IP to session would be as easy as:

```
session_start();  //near beginning of script
$_SESSION['ip'] = $ip;
```

Than on any additional pages after ip value has been set:

```
session_start(); //near beginning of script
if(!empty($_SESSION['ip'])) {
    // do something with it
}
```

I can't think of any reason you would work with the `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` value directly.

I would say though that I don't quite understand why you would need to store this value to session as it would always be available via `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

To answer the use case specified in your comment.  Your code could be as simple as:

```
session_start(); //near beginning of script
if(!isset($_SESSION['ip'])) {
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} else if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $_SESSION['ip']) {
   // invalid session
   // exit program, redirect, or whatever you want to do here
   // just make sure you exit script execution
}
// continue with rest of code
```

Comment: The logic is to save the IP from that the session has been started and to check for it with every request that comes from a page. If they are not equal the protected area can not be accessed.

Comment: @bonny See updated answer for suggestion on how to accomplish this.

Comment: @bonny This is obviously a pretty simplistic view. In the real world, REMOTE_ADDR may not be all that reliable (user could be behind proxy, the value might not be relayed, they are no mobile device and changes cells (and thus IP), etc.), so you might want to consider logging out the mismatches to see if you have some cases where you might be blocking legitimate users.

Comment: Do you know a better secure way to handle this issue without using COOKIES? I mind using COOKIES because they are not safe enough. Thanks.

Comment: @bonny Not safe enough for what?  Here the cookie is doing nothing other than storing the session ID.  The session data is never exposed to the client. This really is the preferred method for passing session ID between client and server.

Comment: Right, and thats why COOKIE hijacking can be avoided. I look for a safe way to login and authenticate an User as it so that hackers have no chance to get sights into the profile of an User.

Comment: @bonny Please don't confuse the passing of session ID cookie with other mechanisms that one should have in place for protecting against cross-site request forgery (CSRF) type of attacks. It is pretty much standard in web development to use cookies for propagating session ID's as other options (such as passing query string parameter) are more problematic from a security standpoint.

Comment: Means you would advise to use COOKIES for this issue?

Comment: @bonny I am not suggestion that cookies should be used for storing any secure information at all.  It is acceptable to use cookies specifically for propagation of session id.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to block connections MIM attack by requiring the IP address not to change? This might be problematic - because IP's don't always stay the same in the real world. However, you could do:

```
<?php

//start a session
session_start();

//check cookie and ip
if((session_id() === $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) && (!isset($_SESSION['ip']) || (isset($_SESSION['ip']) && $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR'] === $_SESSION['ip']))){
    echo 'attempt ok';
} else { 
    die('IP changed');
}

//set ip in session
if(!isset($_SESSION['ip'])){
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: The logic is to save the IP from that the session has been started and to check for it with every request that comes from a page. If they are not equal the protected area can not be accessed.

Comment: @bonny you can use Apache for restrict access to directory base on IP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the **last-login IP** equals to the **current used IP**, you have to store your data on your database instead of using sessions. One of the general behaviour of sessions is that **any session-data is lost after the session** reaches his **end** of life.